# What are the restrictions on the Damion Google Font?

Tags: fonts, logo, licensing

I am working on a new project and I am looking to employ a font for a logo.

"Damion" seems like a great candidate for the logo font.

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Damion

Is this font available for commercial use?

Comment: I am new to this section however I know this is not a duplication because I am looking for an answer to a specific font.

Comment: A specific "Google font", which that question is about, I fail to see how it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Cheers for the downvote. I just wanted to be sure about the usage restrictions of this specific font.

Comment: If that comment is aimed at me, I didn't downvote. I did vote to close though though. Should we have a separate question for every single google font? I don't think so.

Comment: But don't take downvotes personally anyway. Thousands of questions get voted up and down every day, it's not an attack on you, people are free to vote however they want.

Comment: I asked a question and I was looking for an answer. If this was a "duplicate" then I apologise, I am new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer*

The [license](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL_web) states, "The OFL allows the licensed fonts to be **used, studied, modified and
redistributed freely** *as long as they are not sold by themselves*."

It also says, "The
fonts, including any derivative works, can be bundled, embedded, 
redistributed **and/or sold** with any software provided that any reserved
names are not used by derivative works. The fonts and derivatives,
however, *cannot be released under any other type of license*."

This suggests that you are free to use for commercial purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the research & response, can you see any clauses that could cause a problem once a a site becomes heavy traffic site?

Comment: These sort of licenses are generally intended for what you are looking for in my experience.

Comment: Does this mean it's totally free?

Comment: As long as you abide by the terms, you can pretty much use it for anything. Your original question about using it for brand development is generally not going to infringe. 

Don't sell the rights to the font, and don't change the license, otherwise you're pretty much good to go.

Comment: The font is clearly available for use. Thanks for your help. John.